# json data is not showing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a json file that I am trying to access using the following jquery function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/data/coffee.json',
    dataType:'json',
    success: function(data) {
        let widget = show(data);
        $("#Meals").html(widget);
    }
});

function show(data) {
    let statusHtml = '<ul>';
    $.each(data.prices, function(i, meal){
        statusHtml += '<li> name: '+ meal.item + '</li>';
        statusHtml += '<li> price: '+ meal.price + '</li>';
    });
    statusHtml += '</ul>';
    return statusHtml;
}
```

The data I am trying to access is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "shopName": "The Coffee Connection",
    "address": "123 Lakeside Way",
    "phone": "16503600708",
    "prices": [
  {
   "item": "Cafe Latte",
   "price": 4.75
  },
  {
   "item": "Flat White",
   "price": 4.75
  },
  {
   "item": "Cappucino",
   "price": 3.85
  },
  {
   "item": "Single Espresso",
   "price": 2.05
  },
  {
   "item": "Double Espresso",
   "price": 3.75
  },
  {
   "item": "Americano",
   "price": 3.75
  }
  ]
 }
]
```

I have tried to console.log('success', data); and this returns the prices array in the console. But for some reason it is not showing up when I run this code.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: There is the object of prices.

Comment: Is syntax error in the code by accident or in Your original code it is too? I mean `)};` after `$.ajax({`

Comment: That is by accident. I must not have copied it across properly.  I am not getting any errors.  It's just not able to access the prices object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.prices` isn't valid.
`data` is an array, so you need `data[0].prices`, and etc.
loop through `data` first, and that variable would have a prices property.
or just use

```
function show(data) {
    let statusHtml = '<ul>';
    $.each(data[0].prices, function(i, meal){
        statusHtml += '<li> name: '+ meal.item + '</li>';
        statusHtml += '<li> price: '+ meal.price + '</li>';
    });
    statusHtml += '</ul>';
    return statusHtml;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Data is an `Array`, this should work:

```
$.each(data[0].prices, function(i, meal){
    statusHtml += '<li> name: '+ meal.item + '</li>';
    statusHtml += '<li> price: '+ meal.price + '</li>';
});
```